# How to change a Background color of item in a list view conditioned by an option

Tags: android

I have my code:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String elementoSeleccionado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Boolean realizado = getRealizadoPorElemento(elementoSeleccionado);
        if (realizado == true){
            actualizaRealizado(elementoSeleccionado,"N");
            elementosList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        } else if (realizado == false){
            actualizaRealizado(elementoSeleccionado,"S");
            elementosList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3DF400"));
        }
    }
};
```

And this still working, but the problem is here.

I have a Method run the list view and update some with other color:

```
ArrayList<String> elementos = LeerElementosLista();
if (elementos.isEmpty() == false) {
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, LeerElementosLista());
    elementosList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Boolean realizadoelem = false;
    int count = elementosList.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        String elem = elementosList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        realizadoelem = getRealizadoPorElemento(elem);

        if (realizadoelem == true){
            elementosList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3DF400"));
        }
    }
} else {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "No hay Listas para mostrar!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

And just this line in the second method

```
elementosList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3DF400"));
```

is not working, the app closes but I don't have an error in the console.

Comment: provide the logcat output

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the way of doing it.

You need to create a custom adapter, from BaseAdapter class.

There you can set the background color of the cell on the getView() method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How I can implement OnItemClickLisatener and OnLongItemClickListener in a Custom adapter?

Comment: Exactly the same way you are doing with the arrayadapter, the listener is for the list not for the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set drawable/selector instead of color.If you override default background it aloso deletes default selector.So your list is created with one selector and you are trying change it.Maybe here is the conflict.

But better provide logcat output.It would be easier;